# CD tray not responding

Tags: cd, system-tray, cd-drive, scsi

I have an issue with my laptop's CD tray : whenever I put a CD inside, it rotates and then stops following the same cycles for like 5 minutes during which none of the CD related commands and tools respond.

Then it stops spinning but if I try to read it, the same thing happens again.

Here are the commands I've tried and their outputs ( it might not be exact, I'm translating from french) :

```
$ eject
```

Doesn't respond, I can't even cancel with ctrl + c

```
$ eject -v
eject: use default peripheral 'cdrom'
eject: peripheral's name is 'cdrom'
eject: extended peripheral name is '/dev/cdrom'
eject: '/dev/cdrom' is a link of '/dev/sr0'
eject: '/dev/sr0' isn't mounted
eject: '/dev/sr0' isn't a mounting point
eject: '/dev/sr0' isn't a partitionned peripheral
```

and after the 5 minutes, when it finally ejects, I get :

```
eject: attempting to eject '/dev/sr0' with the CD-ROM's ejection command
eject: the CD-ROM's ejection command didn't succeed.
eject: attempting to eject 'dev/sr0' with the SCSI command
eject: the SCSI ejection command succeeded
```

I also tried lshw : when the tray is not responding the command gets stuck at "SCSI" but after the 5 minutes, I get :

```
*-scsi
          hardware ID: 2
          logic name: scsi2
          features: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVDRAM GT51N
             manufacturer: HL-DT-ST
             hardware id: 0.0.0
             information bus: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logic name: /dev/cdrom
             logic name: /dev/cdrw
             logic name: /dev/dvd
             logic name: /dev/dvdrw
             logic name: /dev/sr0
             version: AS00
             features: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
           *-medium
                hardware id: 0
                logic name: /dev/cdrom
```

I tried some solutions that I found online, such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/191522/539162) but nothing worked...

Could it be a hardware problem? Is there a way to be sure?

Comment: Try to liveboot a CD, if you have one, or have another computer you can burn one on.

Comment: I'll try to do that but I can't do it right now