# Cannot mount audio CDs (but DVDs are fine)

Tags: mount, cd

I seem to have lost the ability to mount audio cds - maybe since  upgrading to 17.04? - DVDs mount OK.

Nautilus says "Unable to access "Audio Disk" - Location is not mountable".

Trying to mount manually using `sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom1/` gives me:

```
mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/sr0: can't read superblock
```

`dmesg | tail` then gives me:

```
[  125.618809] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[  125.618811] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0`
[  125.618813] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
[  125.630802] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
[  125.642801] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
[  126.942709] EXT4-fs (sr0): unable to read superblock
[  127.070758] EXT4-fs (sr0): unable to read superblock
[  127.198797] EXT4-fs (sr0): unable to read superblock
[  127.326797] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x0
[  127.326804] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: unable to read squashfs_super_block
```

Also tried `sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom1/ -t iso9660` leading to:

```
mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

And `dmesg | tail`

```
[  127.326797] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x0
[  127.326804] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: unable to read squashfs_super_block
[  147.129330] scsi_io_completion: 93 callbacks suppressed
[  147.129335] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#18 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  147.129337] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#18 Sense Key : Illegal Request     [current] 
[  147.129339] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#18 Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[  147.129341] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#18 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 01 00
[  147.129342] blk_update_request: 93 callbacks suppressed
[  147.129343] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 64
[  147.129367] isofs_fill_super: bread failed, dev=sr0, iso_blknum=16, block=16
```

Not sure where to go from here so grateful for suggestions.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm still stuck! Any pointers on how to debug appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I think it's a kernel bug. I had posted about it [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=227542) and there's a [kernel bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195901) logged that you could follow as well.

Comment: This issue (with mostly same error messages as above) appeared today on my 16.04. VLC works fine. I wonder if there is a new kernel bug.

Answer (score 1):

I've been troubleshooting this for a while and I just downgraded my package of udisks from **2.7**.1-2 to **2.6**.4-1 and rebooted gdm -- instant fix.

It seems there may have been a regression introduced in udisks. I don't see a bug yet, so one should likely need to be opened. If you're looking to play or rip the CDs a couple applications still can (those that don't use Udisks), so try VLC or CDparanoia which I've had good luck with, and then otherwise a fix will hopefully come as soon as possible.

Edit: The latest version of udisks 2.7.1-2 and libblockdev 2.10-1 seem to fix the issue as well. Hopefully the updates come down the pipe soon!

Comment: Thanks a lot Bujiraso. Yes VLC works now (it didn't originally but I wonder if I had a separate issue there), and I'm using Sound Juicer for ripping - which I understand uses CDParanoia - which works great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

### Symptoms (16.04)

1. When music CD is inserted, an error message appears `Unable to access “Audio Disc Location is not mountable`.

[image: Unable to access “Audio Disc Location is not mountable]

2. The CD icon appears in the Ubuntu Launcher as normal but clicking the icon has no effect or brings up the above error message.
3. The CD is not accessible via Nautilus or Rythmbox, but **is accessible** through VLC.

### Solution (16.04)

Try installing gvfs-backends. 
Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt install gvfs-backends
```

For further info, see [Bug: Unable to mount audio disc](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/609020?comments=all)